# Dupe-hammered questions show the wrong badge

Tags: bug, tags, dupehammer, tag-badges

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44060728/1553851) which was dupe hammered by Jon Skeet:
[image: dupe hammer]

The choice to display the [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse) gold badge is surprising, considering that the question also has the higher-priority [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, and Jon has a higher score in the latter. Is this a bug?

Comment: Why is the java tag higher priority? Fewer people have a gold badge for eclipse, so arguably being an expert in that tag counts for more.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant higher as far as tag ordering. Are you saying we use (roughly) the opposite order for this feature?

Comment: I'm on mobile just now but I'm sure this is documented somewhere. Yes, in my experience the 'rare' tag is picked over a popular one.

Comment: And I've been shown to be wrong. The order is 'arbitrary', probably whatever the database spits out as first or last. See the dupe (discussion in the comments there and elsewhere).